# Order relation between Ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Need guidance on this problem. Given the following ordinals, determine the order relation (and equalities) - ($\Omega = 2^{\aleph_0}$)

$\omega_1$, $\Omega \cdot  3$, $\omega \cdot \omega_1$, $3^{\Omega}$, $\Omega^{\omega_1}$

My solution (partial):

$\Omega\cdot 3 \gt \Omega\cdot 2 \gt \Omega$, $3^{\Omega} = \lim_{n \lt \Omega}3^{n} = \Omega$ ($\Omega$ is a limit ordinal)

I'm not certain about how to deal with $\omega \cdot \omega_1$ and $\Omega^{\omega_1}$

The inequalities:

$\Omega\cdot 3 \gt 3^{\Omega} \gt \omega_1$

Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, $\Omega = 2^{\aleph_0}$ is ordinal exponentiation or cardinal exponentiation?

Comment: $\Omega$ is the size of the continuum (cardinal exponentiation). All other exponentiations in this question are in the ordinal sense.

Answer (score 2):

A hint for $\omega\cdot\omega_1$: What does it look like?  Can you simplify it?  (For a simpler example, compare $2\cdot\omega$ and $\omega\cdot2$...)

Comment: $\omega \cdot 2 = \omega + \omega$ while $2 \cdot \omega = \omega$,  so $\omega_1 \gt \omega \cdot \omega_1 \gt \omega$? Also, am I right about the others?

Comment: Not exactly: $\omega\cdot\omega_1$ is the result of concatenating $\omega_1$ copies of $\omega$, and you should see that this is *precisely* $\omega_1$.